# Can't read binary file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles

My code is running but it can't read the output of the binary file I entered. It gave a garbage value. The program is designed to allow a user to choose an option.

1. To add item and write it to binary file.
2. Display an output of binary file that has been read.

Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct info
{
    char name[50];
    int price, quantity;    
};

void AddItem(info item)
{
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Enter the following data about an item: \n";
    cout<<"Item name: ";
    cin.getline(item.name,50);
    cout<<"Price per item: RM";
    cin>>item.price;
    cout<<"Quantity: ";
    cin>>item.quantity;

}

void DisplayItems(info item)
{
    cout<<"Item name: "<<item.name<<endl;
    cout<<"Price per item: "<<item.price<<endl;
    cout<<"Quantity: "<<item.quantity<<endl;    
}

int main()
{
    info item;
    int option;
    char again;

    cout<<"1. Add new item in the product file\n";
    cout<<"2. Display all items\n";
    cout<<"3. Exit\n";
    cout<<"select option: ";
    cin>>option;

    if(option==1)
    {
        fstream file("report.dat", ios::out|ios::binary);
        do
        {
            AddItem(item);
            file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item));
            cout<<"Do you want to enter another record? (Y/N): ";
            cin>>again;
        }
        while(again=='Y'||again=='y');  
    }

    if(option==2)
    {
        fstream file("report.dat", ios::in|ios::binary);
        if(!file)
        {
            cout<<"Error in opening the file!";
            return 0;
        }

       file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item),sizeof(item));
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            DisplayItems(item);
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item),sizeof(item));
        }
        file.close();

    }

    if(option==3)
    {
        cout<<"Exit";
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is how my output looks like:
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'I can't read from the file'? Does it display `Error in opening the file!`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it gave a garbage value"? That's what the content in binary files uses to look like...

Comment: @AnthonyD. you can refer to picture ive attached. the output screen suppose to gimme a value is it?

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
void AddItem(info item)
```

to

```
void AddItem(info& item)
```

so that the user's input in that function, is reflected in the actual argument.

I'd also change the name of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `report.dat` with`repost.txt` 
I'd also re-examine `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item)`
Also if you haven't, open the report file you have created in the program.

Comment: Renaming the file will not have any effect on the code. The program is so basic that it does not take file extension into account when processing it.